# How can I create tables with python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to create my tables with my Python code.
I feel like I'm doing it right but when i execute my code, nothing is happening.

I tried the following code

commands.sql

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS text;

CREATE TABLE text(
    id_text SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    line_number VARCHAR(3),
    line_content VARCHAR(255)
);
```

CreateDB.py

```py
from Utils import ConnectDB as ConnectDBFile


class CreateDB:

    conn = None
    cursor = None
    sql_path = "./commands.sql"
    array_sql_commands = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = ConnectDBFile.ConnectDB.getInstance()
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.setSqlCommands()

    def setSqlCommands(self):
        self.array_sql_commands = open(self.sql_path).read().split(";")

    def createDatabase(self):
        for command in self.array_sql_commands:
            try:
                print("Running : " + command)
                self.cursor.execute(command)
            except :
                print("Command skipped")
```

RunCreation.py

```py
from Utils import CreateDB

obj_create_db = CreateDB.CreateDB()
obj_create_db.createDatabase()
```

Someone knows what is wrong in my code ?
Thanks!

**EDIT :** I'm trying to add manualy the `;` because the `split()` delete it. Now, i've my sql commands ending with `;` but nothing changes in the result.

Comment: I believe that with the `split()` function, you are removing the ; that should be included in the DROP TABLE statement.

Comment: @FelipeSulser Yes, the ```split()``` remove the ```;``` but i don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Just execute the whole script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17261656/895640